# validation error on person picker

Tags: 2010, infopath

I have a couple of person pickers that are causing issues on an InfoPath form published to sharepoint.

I have entered the SharePoint site and groups I want to pick the person from. This works fine however I get inconsistent errors from some users when saving the form:

"The form cannot be submitted because it contains validation errors.  Errors are marked with either..."

".. Field or group:my:group_1: No exact match was found. Check this item(s) that did not resolve for more options."

I don't knwo why this error is appearing:

- The field it not mandatory (there are not required fields in this form)
- The fields are not visible when this error is coming up so they have not been modified since the form was opened
- If i add the user having the issue to the owners group for site collection it works and they don't get the error any more.

  - however some users not in the owners group don't get the error

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the person picker a custom control you created?

Comment: Nope just the standard one you get in InfoPath (2010) - I have given it the site address and SharePoint group I want to be selectable, disallowed multi-select and set it to people only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the user groups used to validate the person picker have:

"Who can view the membership of the group?"  set to "Everyone"

under Group Settings section of edit group in SharePoint.

This (kind of obviously) stops the validation working for anyone not in the this group or the group owner (site owner in this case) if you have it set to "Group Members".